# A kind of permutations and possible relation to cyclic groups.

Tags: matrices, group-theory, permutations, representation-theory, cyclic-groups

Any permutation that moves $n$ elements in some fashion never revisiting the same until all others have been visited, in other words so that:
$${\bf P}^n = {\bf I}, \text{ but no } 0<m<n \text{ s.t. } ({\bf P}^m)_{ii} = 1 \text{ for any } i$$

will $\bf P$ need to be permutation similar to any representation for a generating element of a cyclic group of order $n$?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Take the cycle decomposition of your permutation.  If one of the cycles has length $k<n$ then of course there are elements taken back to themselves in $k$ steps.  So, your assumptions mean you have an $n-$cycle.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I assume that no diagonal element will become 1 for any power of $\bf P$ up until ${\bf P}^n$ when we get identity.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're thinking of a permutation as a matrix (permutation matrix). Your assumption means that $\mathbf{P}^m$ has no fixed points for $0<m<n$, and this is equivalent, as @lulu said, to the permutation being an $n$-cycle. I don't understand what exactly your question is.

Comment: I think a bit what is troubling is that I have not really learned the vocabulary for the things I'm fiddling around with here. I think you are right in how you perceive my question. Does having a $n$-cycle but no $<n$-cycles mean equivalent to a cyclic group of order $n$? I should probably read some book to improve my algebra vocabulary.

Comment: Among permutations of n elements, the following are equivalent: (i) being an n-cycle, (ii) having an n-cycle, (iii) having an n-cycle and no k-cycles for k<n. Any of these equivalent conditions imply the permutation generates a cyclic group of order n. However there are other types of permutations that can generate a cyclic group of order n besides n-cycles - for instance, among permutations of 6 elements, the permutation (1)(23)(456) generates a cyclic group of order 6. (BTW I don't see any need for matrices here.)